# Print first letter of each word C

Tags: c

Im pretty new to C and im struggling with printing the first letter of every word in a string.
i know that i print the first letter of the first word and after that i should search for whitespaces, so i that i know that the next character is definitely the next letter i have to print, but i am not sure how to write the matching code for that.
my written code is garbage, so i didnt post.
i just need some tips to understand how the code has to be written
thanks!

Comment: No tips if you don't show any effort. Can you do it without a programming language, can you explain a procedure that would give the desired result "*an Algorithm*"?

Comment: yea, sorry for that! added my thoughts on a possible procedure now

Comment: Please post the code, it doesn't matter how bad it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of this:

```
void print_first_letters(char *input)
{        
    // Check the argument validity.
    if(input == NULL) return;        
    // Get the length of the input string.
    int length = strlen(input);
    // Print the very first character, if it is a valid one.
    if(input[0] != ' ' && input[0] != '\0') printf("%c\n", input[0]);
    // Loop over the string, character by character.
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){      
        // Check if the current character is a whitespace.      
        if(input[i] == ' '){
            // If there is a next character, and it is NOT a whitespace, print it!
            if(i + 1 < length && input[i + 1] != ' '){
                printf("%c\n", input[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to include string.h for strlen() to work. Alternatively you can pass the length of the input as an argument if the length is known.

Comment: thank you for answering anyways. did i get it right that "i" is counting the whitespaces?

Comment: now ok :) , I like `if(input == NULL || !*input) return;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I didn't know that would work, but if it does, that is indeed a nicer/cleaner way of doing it :)

Comment: @v.lu Since it is definitely working now, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: thank you very much! phil, could you quickly explain me ur code?

Comment: @v.lu I added comments to the code which should explain it.

Comment: @Phil you helped me a lot, thanks for that! and i can see what you did there :-)

Comment: @v.lu you're welcome. If this helped you, it would be appreciated if you accept the answer, and maybe show your thankfulness with an upvote :)