# I want to get user input and return the First Letters of each string

Tags: c

Forgive me, but I am new to C programming.

I am trying to write a code in c where I will request for a user input,say "Hello World". Once user gives this I want to return the initials like "HW".

i have searched online for clues but nothing seem to be giving me enough help even though there have been quite helpful clues to some degree.

Comment: You are not going to learn anything by getting other people to write code for you.

Comment: So, what would happen if the user types in "HelloWorld" ; without a space in between. Or just "Helloworld" ? What output are you expecting then?

Comment: What is the question? _"How to read input from user?"_ or _How to split string into words?_ etc.

Comment: This will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015240/print-first-letter-of-each-word-c

Comment: 'i have searched online for clues but nothing seem to be giving me enough help' OK, what search string/s did you try?

Comment: ...because Googling for  'C get user input and return the First Letters of each string' gives: 'About 2,060,000 results', many from SO.

Comment: Please - search strings from your history?  I'm really interested in what you tried and why it didn't help......

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to read in a string using the "scanf" function in C, then loop over the string and print the first character, and every character that follows a space using the printf function. That should be pretty easy if you do some research.

Comment: Hi, thanks to all of you guys for your help and advice. i have been able to sort this out by getting bits of information here and there. I am happy to share this at any point in time so let me know if anyone is interested. Than you  all again